Upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04 is stuck
I am upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04, but the upgrade is stuck at this state for several hours now. Is this an issue and if so, is there anything I can do about it?


The update process has serious bugs. Do not restart your computer because you may end up with a system with missing graphical interface. Instead, download the iso of 24.04 and flash it to a USB drive. And use it to fresh install 24.04 (you can also use it for data backup if something goes wrong in the upgrade).
